# Are all reactions with ΔG < 0 spontaneous?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, free-energy

Given the formula $\Delta G = \Delta H - T\Delta S$. It is commonly written that **all** spontaneous reactions necessarily have $\Delta G < 0$. I was curious if the converse is true: Are **all** reactions with $\Delta G < 0$ spontaneous. If not, why?

Comment: Yes they are spontaneous from a thermodynamic point of view. Kinetics is another matter...

Comment: Will a reaction with ΔG < 0, involving thermodynamically unstable, but kinetically stable reactants be considered spontaneous, then?

Comment: yes spontaneous. Thermodynamics does not involve time at all, just energy changes and heat will be given out in such a reaction. With a catalyst this may be  fast if not can be incredibly slow, eons.  Spontaneous should not be confused with,  as it were, 'it will happen as we watch it'. Kinetically slow, thermodynamically spontaneous is very common, thankfully; its the state we all exists in in an oxygen atmosphere :)

Comment: @porphyrin That comment is just good as an answer. Do you please mind writing one? ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, Gibbs energy is only the relevant state function in the special case of constant temperature and pressure.

In the [wording of IUPAC](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/A/A00178.html):

> partial derivative of Gibbs energy with respect to extent of reaction at constant pressure and temperature [is negative] for spontaneous reactions

In the special case of constant temperature and volume, Helmholtz energy is the relevant state function.

Most generally, a process is spontaneous if the entropy of the universe (system + surroundings) increases.